# Selenium: Chrome not reachable after some steps of my specflow feature are executed

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation, specflow

I am running my UI tests on a Windows 10 self-hosted agent in Azure DevOps. The test starts working fine, but after certain steps I start to get a "Chrome not reachable" error. I am not sure why this is happening. What puzzles me is that when I run the same tests on my old Windows 2012 self-hosted agent they run fine.

Both of them have the same version of Chrome and the chrome driver is being bundled using nuget.

This are the logs I am receiving

```
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}) on port 62049
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Starting ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}) on port 62156
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
  X DismissAnAlert("North",null) [39s 791ms]

  Standard Output Messages:
 C:\vstsagent\A4\_work\r5\a\_MyProject Automation UI Tests\AutomationTests
 When I select a  specific "North" area and click on go to Alerts
 -> done: SelectMonitoringAreasSteps.WhenISelectASpecificAreaAndClickOnGoToAlerts("North") (3.8s)
 And I click on the first alert to view
 -> done: AlertsSteps.WhenIClickOnTheFirstAlertToView() (3.3s)
 Then I should see options to convert or dismiss an alert are displayed
 -> error: chrome not reachable
   (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
 When I select option to "dismiss" an incident
 -> skipped because of previous errors
 Then I should see warning message as "Are you sure you want to dismiss this alert"
 -> skipped because of previous errors
 When I click on Dismiss alert button
 -> skipped because of previous errors
 Then the alert should be dismissed and should be disappeared from map and alert queue
 -> skipped because of previous errors
 And I should see that dismissed alert has been audited in the audit log table
 -> skipped because of previous errors

Error Message:
       OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : chrome not reachable
      (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
    TearDown : OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : chrome not reachable
      (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.129)
      Stack Trace:
         at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElementByCssSelector(String cssSelector)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.By.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<CssSelector>b__0(ISearchContext context)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(By by)
       at MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests.Pages.AlertsPage.get_AlertMonitoringAreaElement() in c:\vstsagent\A3\_work\16\s\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\Pages\AlertsPage.cs:line 28
       at MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests.Pages.AlertsPage.GetAlertCardDetails() in c:\vstsagent\A3\_work\16\s\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\Pages\AlertsPage.cs:line 53
       at MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests.Steps.AlertsSteps.ThenIShouldSeeOptionsToConvertOrDismissAnAlertAreDisplayed() in c:\vstsagent\A3\_work\16\s\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\Steps\AlertsSteps.cs:line 125
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStepMatch(BindingMatch match, Object[] arguments)
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.ExecuteStep(IContextManager contextManager, StepInstance stepInstance)
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnAfterLastStep()
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.CollectScenarioErrors()
       at MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests.TestFeatures.DismissAlertFeature.ScenarioCleanup()
       at MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests.TestFeatures.DismissAlertFeature.DismissAnAlert(String monitoring, String[] exampleTags) in c:\vstsagent\A3\_work\16\s\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\TestFeatures\DismissAlert.feature:line 14
    --TearDown
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
       at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.GetScreenshot()
       at MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests.Steps.Initialiser.TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver) in c:\vstsagent\A3\_work\16\s\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\Steps\Initialiser.cs:line 131
       at MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests.Steps.Initialiser.CloseDriver() in c:\vstsagent\A3\_work\16\s\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests\Steps\Initialiser.cs:line 86
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Bindings.BindingInvoker.InvokeBinding(IBinding binding, IContextManager contextManager, Object[] arguments, ITestTracer testTracer, TimeSpan& duration)
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.InvokeHook(IBindingInvoker invoker, IHookBinding hookBinding, HookType hookType)
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType)
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Infrastructure.TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioEnd()
       at TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunner.OnScenarioEnd()
       at MyCompanyMyProject.Automation.Tests.TestFeatures.DismissAlertFeature.TestTearDown()
```

Comment: Hi, does this issue occur if you run the test locally? Apart from chrome, also make sure the chrome driver,  selenium web driver are latest versions. Also, you can try starting chrome with `--no-sandbox`.

Comment: Running them locally on my computer or in the build server? I have no issues when running this on my Win10 box

Comment: This is a hard issue. It could be a virus scanner, memory issues, the VM could be CPU-bound, I/O bound... The list goes on. My gut instinct is that the VM in Azure is running slow for some reason.

Comment: Having this issue on a Microsoft hosted agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the exact reason for this issue by adding a video recorder option.
Create a file named webapp.runsettings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
<!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
<!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
<DataCollectionRunSettings>
<DataCollectors>
 <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/VideoRecorder/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder.VideoRecorderDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="Screen and Voice Recorder">
 <!--Video data collector was introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 -->
 </DataCollector>
</DataCollectors>
</DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

You can enable the video recording option and can point to this file from the task given in the pipeline which runs the test